# Opening both PhpStorm and WebStorm or just two PhpStorm windows?

Tags: phpstorm, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I am working on both the backend and the front end of a project, and was wondering if opening 2 PhpStorm windows was the better than one WS and one PS ?

Comment: It depends what exactly you need to do but in general: 2 windows of the same IDE will eat less resources (RAM) and require less configuration (no need to config the same thing twice). PhpStorm = WebStorm + PHP + DB/SQL (some plugins will have to be installed manually as they are not bundled by default)... therefore it can handle both front and back end parts... maybe even in the same project/workspace (as you can open 2nd project as separate node in the Project View -- not ideal (not proper "independent" project) but allows to access the files).

Comment: But if you need to use some windows that once opened takes the focus (some modal window) in both projects at the same time ... then having 2 separate IDE (or 2 **separate instances** of the same IDE (which will have separate configs)) is better. Separate instances (IDEs or configs) may also help if you are having issues with identifying which project you are currently using ... as you can have different Color Style or GUI Theme .. so it's easier to differentiate between instances/projects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do back-end and front-end as well, and actually prefer to have just 1 PhpStorm window open. I don't really see the benefit in having multiple windows.

But, if you really want 2 windows, I'd say go with 2 PhpStorm windows. PhpStorm does everything WebStorm does anyway. Unless you like the different icon to never get confused which window is back-end and which one is front-end.

Ultimately, it's up to you. Try both for a while and see what works best.

Comment: How do you manage two projects in the same window though ? line when you want to open a terminal, is it project aware ? when you Ctrl + N to navigate to a class, is there a way to make it look for classes in current project ?

Comment: @AbderrahmaneTAHRIJOUTI For my situation, front-end and back-end are usually within the same project. And if I have to run multiple things via terminal then I do this in separate Terminal windows outside of PhpStorm.